# Extjs File upload using json service?

Tags: json, file-upload, extjs, ria, extjs4.1

I am using json service(.net RIA service) to push data to server from Extjs. Currently I have a requirement to upload document to server. I saw some examples using form submit to php files.

Is this possible through json service? or Is it necessery to create some server logic where i can accept form submits?

Is it possible to read some binary data from client side and push as json data to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Extjs, File uploads are not performed using normal 'Ajax' techniques, that is they are not performed using XMLHttpRequests. Instead a hidden  element containing all the fields is created temporarily and submitted with its target set to refer to a dynamically generated, hidden  which is inserted into the document but removed after the return data has been gathered.

Be aware that file upload packets are sent with the content type multipart/form and some server technologies

check : http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-hasUpload

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. You should use `FileReader` to get binary base64 encoded content (`FileReader.readAsDataURL(Blob|File)`), which you can transfer with JSON.

More insights here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: As far as I know, ExtJS doesn't support the html5 client-side file stuff.

Comment: You can integrate them yourself, ExtJS is just a javascript framework, nothing more nothing less. In my projects I'm using ExtJS4.1 with Websockets, WebRTC and some minor html5 features like FileReader or Blobs, without any trouble or conflicts.

Comment: offtopic, Slava do you have any writings on using extjs with websockets?

Comment: Sure: https://gist.github.com/4040476 This is 2 basic mixin which I'm using one for Controller other for Store. I didn't plan to publish them so they are little rough for internal use. It's coffeescript compile them, if you need javascipt version: http://coffeescript.org/